# Is it possible to build a WSO2 distribution with ESB and api gateway?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I want to deploy only one carbon product (one JVM) containing the ESB component and the api gateway component.
Is it possible to build this kind of application ? Is there any reference documentation explaining how to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Carbon-based product comprise of a set of installable/uninstallable features. You can get an ESB pack and install API manager features on it (can do this via the management console UI). However you won't be able to put together mismatching versions of the features (features released for different carbon platform versions/components) so this is subject to availability of matching components. [This documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Feature+Management) on feature management will give you some insights on how to do it. (There can be cases where components may be in total conflict though)

But if your requirement is just running two products on the same machine, you can consider running them with port offsets, which is easier.